# Get-Help cmdlet not working with implicit remoting

Tags: powershell

**Summary:**
I have several functions that are placed on a remote windows server built for implicit remoting. However, I am unable to utilize the Get-Help cmdlet to show the synopsis that I put into each of the functions that I created, so these are ***not*** native powershell cmdlets. The get-help cmdlet works fine with the scripts are running locally.

**Question:**
Is it not possible to use Get-Help with implicit remoting?

Edit 1.

Attempting Briantists fix

```
PS> $module = Import-Module 'tmp_2c0mhyix.ivb' -PSSession $sessVar -PassThru
Import-Module : Failure from remote command: Import-Module -Name 'tmp_2c0mhyix.ivb': The specified module 'tmp_2c0mhyix.ivb' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:11
+ $module = Import-Module 'tmp_2c0mhyix.ivb' -PSSession $sessVar-Pa ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (tmp_2c0mhyix.ivb:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Tried this as well with out the module name as well.

```
PS> $module = Import-Module -PSSession $sessVar-PassThru
Import-Module : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:11
+ $module = Import-Module -PSSession $sessVar-PassThru
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-Module], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Comment: If you have the module name, you don't need to reimport it, just use it with `Get-Command`. Also I didn' tmean to imply that these commands will fix anything (they won't), it was just to give you visibility into how implicit remoting is implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit remoting is a strange beast. It creates proxy functions in a temporary module, and it's the proxy functions that get called locally.

After you call `Import-PSSession`, call `Get-Module` and you'll see one with a weird tmp name.

Alternatively, you can import the module initially using this method `$module = Import-Module -PSSession $mySession -PassThru` to get the module returned in a variable.

Then you can call `Get-Command -Module $module` to see the functions, but check out the definition:

```
Get-Command -Module $module | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Definition
```

[Shay Levy goes into detail about proxy functions here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/03/01/proxy-functions-spice-up-your-powershell-core-cmdlets/), and you can see that they do include instructions for `Get-Help` so that it can find the right help topic, but when the command is on the other side of the remoting, I don't think those would work.

I don't know if I've ever tried using help for functions imported that way, so maybe it actually does work and it's just a bug you've found, but I feel like this info would still be helpful.

Comment: Hey Brian, I am following your guide here. I located the tmp file, I ran your command and I am seeing some errors that I will put into the question for ease of reading.

Comment: This is good stuff, I am going to change the way I am remoting a little bit. Using import-pssession  seems significantly faster than the export counterpart I was using.

Comment: I believe this is the  best possible answer. Although there is no perfect fix this led me to a better possible solution, and more effecient ps sessions for my users. Thanks again man.